# Chameleon effect API

Tags: development, conky

Is there a way to interact with the chameleon effect in Ubuntu? I would like to extract the current "theme color" and change the background color of conky accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the script that i think is used to achieve that effect.
[Developers G+ announcement](https://plus.google.com/u/0/117867558830601601230/posts/LGHt9zzAPWp)